# Regex- match third character

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, this is my string "RL5XYZ" and I want to check the third character is it 5 or some other number.
I would like to do this with the Regex, without substring.

Comment: Will it always be the third character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its always going to be checking for the existence of two characters followed by a 5 which is then followed by something else then you could simply check

`/..5*/`

if you want to get the third character (assuming its always a digit) then you could use.

`/..(\d)*/`

You'll get results back from regEx like this:

`` Match 1
Full match  0-3 `RL5`
Group 1.    2-3 `5`
Match 2
Full match  3-5 `XY` ``

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: /..(\d)*/ This gives 3 matches for R0a0XYZ

Comment: Thank you, Code Uniquely, your explanation helped me and now my final Regex is looking like this:
**/^\d{2}5\w{7}/**

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to check whether the third character of a string is a number, you can use the following regex:

```
/^..[0-9]/
```

- `^` Means the match must occur at the start of the string
- . Means match any character (we do this twice)
- [0-9] Means match a number character in the range 0-9. You can actually adjust this to be a different range.

You can also condense the `.` using the following notation

```
/^.{2}[0-9]/
```

The number in braces basically means repeat the previous operator twice.

You can also rewrite the character set [0-9] as \d.

```
/^.{2}\d/
```

To match in JS, simple call exec against the pattern you've created:

/^.{2}\d/.exec('aa3') // => ["aa3", index: 0, input: "aa3"]
   /^.{2}\d/.exec('aaa') // => null

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = 'RL5XYZ';
var position = 3;
var match = '5';

position--;
var r = new RegExp('^[^\s\S]{'+position+'}'+match);

console.log(input.match(r));
```

**position** to check where is to find and **match** what to find

edit: I forgot a ^

Comment: [^\s\S]{3} means three times no whitespace and no non-whitespace. This will never match anything

Comment: do you try it? @LeonhardTriendl

Comment: we don't care about first 2 positions, we care about third one, before do it I rest 1 to position

Comment: sorry i missed the position--. But what's the purpose of [^\s\S]? in Firefox i get a match but not on regex101.com

Comment: the purpose is to be "anything", I probe it in nodejs console

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the third character is a digit you can use

```
.{2}\d.*
```

But . matches everything so maybe you prefer:

```
\w{2}\d\w*
```

`\w{2}` means any of this `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` two times.
`\d` means any digit
`\w*` means any of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` zero or multiple times